# I can’t access my wp admin dashboard

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I take it this question must have popped here a few times so will try keep it sweet and simple:

after having done a fresh wp install via ftp, the following url https://v2.mysitename.com/wp-login.php takes me to the login page. Once I hit log in, that takes me to https://v2.mysitename.com/

My issue here is that I cant access the wp dashboard… I have tried the following:
https://v2.mysitename.com/wp-admin/
https://v2.mysitename.com/wp-admin/index.php
https://v2.mysitename.com/wp-admin/admin.php

No joy so far…running out of ideas and hoping a good soul will shed some light here please!
Thank you,
Jose

Comment: What do you mean you can't access it?

Comment: Hi Paul. When I try any of the url's mentioned above, I get the following error : Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page